# ArgoWF steps output is not getting right value

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

```yaml
  entrypoint: entrypoint
  templates:
    - name: entrypoint
      steps:
        - - name: download
            template: download
            continueOn:
              failed: true
        # - - name: perform-some-tasks
        #     template: perform-some-tasks
        - - name: print-message
            template: print-message
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: message
                  value: "{{steps.download.outputs.result}}"
```

Here are my those download and print-message tasks

```yaml
    - name: download
      container:
        image: my-image
    - name: print-message
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: message
      container:
        image: alpine:latest
        command: [sh, -c]
        args: ["echo result was: {{inputs.parameters.message}}"]
```

`steps.download.outputs.result` I was expecting some value but argo simply passes the complete string `"{{steps.download.outputs.result}}"` to `print-message` step.

How to get the rendered value of `steps.download.outputs.result` in my next step ?